# Performing calculation on the contents of two files

Tags: shell, arithmetic

`file1` contains `100` as its content, and `file2` contains `200`. How would I perform calculation on those two numbers in the terminal? Say I would like to perform division on those two numbers. My approach was `echo $(cat file1)/$(cat file2)`, but it prints `100/200`. I would like to get the value of the division as output.

My original intent was to find out my machine's battery percentage from the terminal. There were two files under `/sys/class/power_suply/BAT1`, which were `energy_now` and `energy_full`. To get the current battery charge in percentage, I would need to get the value of `100 * energy_now / energy_full`

Comment: Do you want **general** shell answers, or do you have a particular shell in mind?

Comment: @glennjackman I am using WSL (Ubuntu). Any answer that will perform okay will do :)

Answer (score 2):

There's umpteen ways to skin a cat. Depending on your shell version, you can do "Arithmetic Expansion" (cf. `man bash`):

```
> echo $(($(cat file1)/$(cat file2)))
0
```

Zero is the unsatisfatory but correct result as `bash` can do integer arithmetics only. Reversing the files, the result is more evident:

```
> echo $(($(cat file2)/$(cat file1)))
2
```

If your system has `bc` (`man bc` - An arbitrary precision calculator language) installed, try

```
> echo "scale=2; $(cat file1)/$(cat file2)" | bc
.50
```

And, there are plenty of text processing and/or scripting languages (`awk`, `perl`, `python`, etc.) that can easily yield your desired result.

Comment: note that `zsh` does floating point arithmetic flawlessly, but you will have convert at leas one of the numbers to float explicitly: `zsh> echo $(( float( $(< file1) ) / $(< file2) ))`

Answer (score 1):

There is a special tool for that - `calc`

Do

```
$ sudo apt install calc
$ man calc
```

and all you command line or inside-script calculation needs would be solved.

If you are using bash for shell, you can use some [primitive arithmetic](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-arithmetic.php). But that is integer only. If you need decimal point - `calc`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the arbitrary precision `dc` calculator to first push the two numbers to the calculator's stack, set the scale to 2 (i.e. ask for two decimal places in the calculated result), calculate the division of the two numbers, and print the result:

```bsh
{ cat file1 file2; echo '2k/p'; } | dc
```

`dc` is a calculator that uses [reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).  In the above command, `dc` will be given `100` and `200` from the two files and `2` from the output of `echo`.  The first command is `k`, which pops the top-most number off the stack (2) and uses it to set the scale.  The next command is `/`, which pops the two top numbers off the stack and divides them.  It then pushes the result back onto the stack.  The `p` command prints the top-most number of the stack (the result of the division).